# Can I include an autocomplete field with <ChipInput> in material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can I include an autocomplete field with  in material UI?
I want the user to see a drop down list, which they can select something from, and then display it as a chip.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [material-ui-chip-input](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input) extension library. Example [here](https://teamwertarbyte.github.io/material-ui-chip-input/?selectedKind=ChipInput&selectedStory=with%20auto%20complete&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel).

```
<ChipInput dataSource=['a', 'b', 'c'] />
```